# Why is there a white space along side certain div segments creating an unneccesary scroll option to the right?

Tags: html, css

So I've noticed in my website that there if you scroll to the right (not as if there is any content to the right) there is a long vertical white strip. This is only if you scroll that you'll see it. This is only alongside certain div elements. Once I get to the rows, the content just stretches to the extra space to the right rather than have the white space as well. Since the problem isn't consistent, I've included all the HTML and CSS code to see if there may be two problems in two separate locations.

This is the **HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ACA Technology</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyWebsite.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="infoHeader" class="header">
<div id="header_container">
<!-- header -->
<header  class="header_shadow nav_type_12 sticky_header  header_to_shrink clearfix" >
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px">
            <h2><a href="#" id="theName"> EAZYnetz </a></h2>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px">      
          <button id="home" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><a href="#Home" style="color:white" style="text-decoration:none"> Home</a></button>   
          <button id="ourApps" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><a href="#OurServices" style="color:white"> Our Services</a></button>
          <button id="contactUs" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="#ContactUs" style="color:white"> Contact Us</a></button>
    </div>
</div><!-- end panel-footer -->
</div>
</div>

<div class="Home">
      <div id="bigPicture" class="container" align="center">
        <h1>BUILD YOUR EMPIRE.</h1>
        <p>Every idea needs a website to express itself. Tell us what you need and how you'll like it. We'll make the layout, animation, and paint the final picture to your future method of advertisement.</p>

      </div>
    </div>


<div id="OurServices">

<div id="information" class="row">
    <h3 align="center"> What's included in any option </h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Your preferences</h3>
        <p> Every idea needs a website to express itself. Tell us what you need and how you'll like it, then we'll make it perfect.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Layout</h3>
        <p> Tell us how you want everything formatted and where to place what according to your liking. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Content</h3>
        <p>What do you want to show your costumers? What do you want them to see? Put whatever you want to express on your webpage, no limits.</p>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="servicesInfo" class="row">
    <h3 align="center"> Choices to pick from</h3>
    <hr>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Front End </h3>
            <p>This consists of content text only.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3> Front End + Design </h3>
            <p>This consists of the content text and the design (colors, layout, menu, animation, etc).  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Whole Package <br> Front End + Design + Databases </h3>
            <p> This is the whole package. It consists of the text of the website, design of the website, and the databases(forums, users, etc) in the website. <p>
        </div>
        <p> Overall price depends on level of complexity and number of pages </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ContactUs" class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 647-550-3998</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> temporary@easynetz.net</li>
        </ul>  
        <p> If you're interested or have any questions or concerns,<br> feel free to contact us. </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the **CSS**

```
a{
     font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;   
}
p{
     font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;   
     font-size: 25px;
}
h1, h2, h3{
     font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;   
     font-size: 35px;

}
li{
    font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;    
     font-size: 25px;
     color: #FFFFFF
}
#infoHeader{
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #1A1C27;

}
.header button{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

.header a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 

}
.Home{  
    height: 573px;
    background-image: url("clouds.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.Home h1,h2,h3{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
.Home p{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;

}
.Home .container h1{
    margin-top: 170px;
}
.top button{
     background-color: black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#theName{
    color: white;

}

#information{
background-color: #68ABDD;
}
#information h3{
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
#information p{

text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff;
}


#servicesInfo h3{
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
#servicesInfo p{

text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff;
}

#servicesInfo{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#ContactUs{
    height: 635px;  
    padding:0!important; 
    margin:0 !important;
    background-image: url("http://hdwallpaperspretty.com/wp-content/gallery/beautiful-buildings-wallpapers/Best-top-desktop-3d-buildings-wallpapers-hd-3d-buildings-wallpaper-13.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#ContactUs{
    color: white;
}

#contactHeader{

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following class to your CSS

```
#information, #servicesInfo {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix the problem. I'm not sure if I marked your answer as an answer, I'm still new-ish, please tell me if I didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can fix that with adding the next css to the html tag on the html file or  target the html on the css file:

```
overflow-x:hidden
```

The overflow means scrolling when the elements on the page are too big for the page. I didn't check your code to the end in order to see which element is too big for the page but this is a quick way to fix that.

The best option though is to check which element is too big and resize it with css in which way you want to.

One way is 
     max-width:100%;